# Finding a basis for a free module

Tags: modules, cyclic-groups, free-modules

Let ***q*** $\in$ $\Bbb Q^3$, such that the elements of ***q*** are positive numbers. Let ***M*** $\subset \Bbb Z^3$ be defined as

$\hspace{3in}$***M*** = $\{ \mathbf n \in \Bbb Z^3 | \mathbf n \cdot \mathbf q \in \Bbb Z \}$,

where  $\cdot$  denotes the usual vector dot product.

It is easy to see that ***M*** is a free $\Bbb Z$-module and my task is to find a basis for it. What I have so far is that if $\mathbf q = \left( \frac{k_1}{m_1}, \frac{k_2}{m_2}, \frac{k_3}{m_3}\right)$, where $k_i, m_i \in \Bbb Z$, then $\{ \left( m_1, 0, 0\right), \left( 0, m_2, 0\right), \left( 0, 0, m_3\right) \}$ is a set of linearly independent elements of ***M***. However, this is not a basis of ***M*** in general (just see the case $\mathbf q = \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$), but I believe that if $\mathbf n = \left( n_1, n_2, n_3 \right)$ is an element of such a basis, then $n_i \leq m_i$, for $i = 1,2,3$.

I am fairly new to the study of modules and I have been trying to find a theorem or anything that could help me, but people with more experience may know better. In fact, I don't really need a general solution but just a good enough algorithm for small enough values of $m_i$. What I have been doing is that I generate the set $\{ (n_1, n_2, n_3) | n_i \leq m_i \}$ by computing a cartesian product and then selecting the elements whose dot product with **q** results in an integer (not counting the zero vector). Then the three vectors with the smallest norm give me a basis for ***M***, but this seems very inefficient. Maybe there is a smarter way to achieve this.

Comment: Having only one nonzero coordinate in the basis vectors is not sufficient, e.g. in the given example we need to generate also $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is why I stated that $\{ (m_1, 0, 0), (0, m_2, 0), (0, 0, m_3) \}$ is not a basis in general. What I end up doing is, for example, in the case $\mathbf q = \left( 1/2, 1/2, 1/2 \right)$ I generate the set $\{ (n_1, n_2, n_3) | 0 < n_i \leq 2, \}$ which gives me the elements $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), ...$. After computing their dot product with **q**, I get that the three vectors with smallest norm that belong to ***M*** are $(0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)$ which in fact form a basis.